# Visual Studio Unit test: Internal Error Unable to start test host

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm unable to run my unit test, when i run in debug mode i get the error: "Internal error: Unable to start test host. Exception: Timeout, process id not set"

My test timeout is set to int.Max so it doesn't seem like a Timeout issue, maybe a configuration issue.
I'm using visual studio for mac 8.3.10

[Test Results screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEayT.png)

Comment: Probably going to need the IDE log and the output from the test runner. Looking at the code that [error](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/fb12ccb7f4245eca20803661deaa37ead0ec35af/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestRunAdapter.cs#L280) seems to mean that the test runner did not start.

Comment: I have similar error today `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Timeout, process id not set.` .  I am using visual studio for mac on catalina . I could not find any solution on web

Comment: Found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2260) but not sure if it is the same issue

Comment: i updated to visual studio latest 8.5.5 and everything works fine now